# Attempting Parametrized Unit Test of Tornado Websockets Server

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, pytest, tornado

I'm trying run a parametrized unit test on a web-socket server (tornado) using vscode and pytest.
I used the sample code from https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html and it works.

However, if I then adapt it to:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_token, is_closed", [( "", True), ("12345", False), (None, True)])
@tornado.testing.gen_test
def test_websocket_is_not_valid(self, input_token, is_closed):
    from tornado.escape import json_encode

    ws_url = "ws://localhost:" + str(self.get_http_port()) + "/"
    ws_client = yield tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(ws_url)
    response = yield ws_client.read_message() #don't care about this one
    token = {"token" : "input_token"}
    ws_client.write_message(message=json_encode(token)) # has to be the first message after a connection
    assert ws_client.stream._closed == is_closed
```

VSCode does not detect multiple tests, but when I try to run it I get this:

> TypeError: test_websocket_is_not_valid() missing 2 required positional
>   arguments: 'input_token' and 'is_closed'

I am pretty new to python so I'm not sure if there is something very basic that I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if gen_test is compatible with other decorators like pytest's. If you want to use pytest, consider avoiding the tornado.testing module entirely and just use pytest-tornado or pytest-asyncio.

Comment: I had a feeling this is probably the reason. I also re-evaluated the architecture of what I'm doing and I think I'm doing too much in one test and need to break this up into smaller pieces.